# c++ How do i end a while loop that add numbers without using a number as a trigger to end the loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a program that adds numbers continuously until the user enters a word or something to stop the program. Currently, I used -9999 but what if the user want to add -9999? I'm new at this can someone help please.

```
float Addition()
{
    Sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter number you wish to add:" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    while(num != -9999)
    {
        Sum += num;
        cout << "Sum is:" << Sum << endl;
        cout << "Please enter number or enter -9999 to exit" << endl;
        cin >> num;

        if(!cin.good())
        {
            throw exception();
        }                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the input as a string instead, then turn it into a number. If what the user entered can't be parsed as a number, stop the loop (just an idea).

Comment: There's always [break](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) that ends a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to change the loop to:

```
while (cin >> num)
```

This will continue to prompt for input until ean nd of file condition which, depending on your operating system, is signaled by typing either <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>.

Comment: It's Control-D instead of Control-C isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it is... Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is long time ago, it's my question when I start learning C++, too. Since the topic is not closed yet, I'd like to share Adarsh Kunwar's idea from this post: [How can we take numeric input until letters are entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64307099/how-can-we-take-numeric-input-until-letters-are-entered)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
float Addition() {
    float Sum = 0, num;
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter number to add: " << endl;
    while (cin >> num) {
        ch = char(num);
        if (ch < '0' && ch > '9')
            break;
        Sum += num;
        cout << "Sum is:" << Sum << endl;
        cout << "Enter any non-numeric character to exit" << endl;
    }
    return Sum;
}
int main() {
    Addition();
    return 0;
}
```

Another solution found and no variable "ch" needed:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
float Addition() {
    float Sum = 0, num;
    for(;;) {
        cout << "Enter number to add: ";
        if(cin >> num) {
            Sum += num;
            cout << "Sum is:" << Sum << endl;
            cout << "Enter any non-numeric character to exit" << endl;
        }
        else break;
    }
    return Sum;
}
int main() {
    Addition();
    return 0;
}
```