# How can we take numeric input until letters are entered?

Tags: c++, input

```
cout << "Enter the numbers to be stored (end with a letter): "; 
cin >> number;
while(!(cin.fail())){
    numbers.push_back(number);
    cin >> number;
}
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
    node->insertKey(numbers.at(i));
}
int search;
cout << "Which number do you want to look up? ";
cin >> search;
```

I want to take numbers from user input until the user enters a letter.

Thereafter I want to take another user input. My output works fine. So when I enter a letter, it stops. But it does not ask for the second input. How can I fix this?

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to rewrite everything to use `std::getline` to read each line of input, and then parse it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When `cin` fails [error flags are set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/), you need to [clear](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) those.

In adition you'll need to clear the `stdin` buffer which will contain whatever characters where not parsed in the previous `cin`.

```
//...
std::cin.clear(); //clear flags
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //clear buffer
//...
int search;
cout << "Which number do you want to look up? ";
cin >> search;
//...
```

Comment: The clear/ignore needs to be before the attempt to stream to `search`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy, yes, my bad, copy/pasted incorrectly. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better to do it like this first:

```
while (cin >> number)
    numbers.push_back(number);
```

The above leaves an empty `vector` if they type a character before any valid number, while your original code pushes a nonsense number onto the `vector`.

Then if they've typed a letter, the `cin` stream will be placed into error state and still have that character input, which you'll want to get rid of:

```
// clear stream errors
cin.clear();
// actually get rid of the line with the character on it...
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You can then carry on with the for loop and stream to `search`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help

```
cout << "Enter the numbers to be stored (end with a letter): "; 
cin >> number;
while(cin>>number){
    if(((char)number>='a' && (char)number<='z')||((char)number>='A' && (char)number<='Z'))break;
    numbers.push_back(number);
    cin >> number;
}
for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
    node->insertKey(numbers.at(i));
}
int search;
cout << "Which number do you want to look up? ";
cin >> search;
```